# NTFS External Drive folders and files permissions as question marks

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I have external Hard drive with **NTFS FS**, and no files or folders appears when I open it Desktop.

When I try to list the files and folders in it, **ls** command gives me **Question marks** as permissions.

I tried to **chmod a+X**, it gives No such file or directory.

I tried to fix partition with **ntfsfix**, and show no errors.

```
d?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? DRP
d?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? WORK
d?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? MOVIES
d?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? New folder
d?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? Evolution
d?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? Ring Tones
d?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? Series
```

Comment: How did you mount the drive? And do you have ntfs-3g installed?

Comment: Yes I have ntfs-3g installed, and I mount it with command **mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 disk**